# How to compute difference between two activerecord instances?

Tags: activerecord, difference

Model structure 
class A {} 
class B {has_many: A} 

Now I have two instances of B, 
b1 = has 3 instances of A having IDs [1,2,3] 
b2 = has 2 instances of A having IDs [1,2] 
How do I compute differences between b1 and b2, which gives me differences in associations too?

Answer (score 0):

Use array subtraction.  You might need to make sure your activerecord relation is converted into an array.

```
b2_missing = b1.as.pluck(:id).to_a - b2.as.pluck(:id)
```